# Algolia Reverse Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

Is there an implementation for reverse searching?

For example, I have model `post`

```
post1 = "Post 1 contains words like Apple, Orange, and Grape."

post2 = "Post 2 contains words like Car, Bike, and Truck."
```

I also have model `tag_group`

```
tag_group1 = [apple]
tag_group2 = [apple, orange]
tag_group3 = [bike, car]
```

How can I find all relevant tags groups that include words found in post1.

`ie: post1 = tag_group1, tag_group2`

Would welcome any ruby gem that can also accomplish a similar task.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index of `tags`, you can perform a query with all the words of post1 as optional words with `query="Post 1 contains words like Apple, Orange, and Grape."&optionalWords="Post 1 contains words like Apple, Orange, and Grape."`

This query will return all tags containing at least one word of post1. You can sort the results by number of matched words by putting `words` as the first element of the ranking formula. By default the sort is first done by number of typos and them by number of matched word